# json parse - unescaping the quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, json

so i am using json to pass some information from one place to another...

i have:

```
message.title = 'this is only a "test"';
```

so obviously, when i use JSON.stringify, i get escaped quotes.

What i want to know is, what is the best way to unescape those quotes when using JSON.Parse.
i have:

```
var message = JSON.parse(message);
var original = ????;
var final = ????;
var regex = new RegExp(original, 'g');
for(var prop in message){
   message.data[prop] = message.data[prop].replace(regex, final);
}
```

I wish to know if i am doing something wrong and, as i tried various values in 'original' and 'final', what are correct values for them.

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to do with the parsed object?

Comment: thanks Ray, it is solved, it was my mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What i want to know is, what is the best way to unescape those quotes when using JSON.Parse

Do nothing. Parsing JSON will decode escapes. (If that doesn't work, then something is breaking between the data being converted to JSON and being parsed, or the data was bad to begin with)

Comment: you sir, are absolutely right. the problem was in how the post to PHP treats the data. I should have mentioned that i was using WordPress in the middle, sorry.